# Javascript - Auto Calculating Body Mass Index

Tags: javascript, indexing

To calc Body Mass Index I have this javascript with two input field for height and weight and one input filed to display output of calculating.

How to display che calc automatically in the BMI field?

**HTMl**

```
<h2>Height=<input type="text" id="hgt"></h2>

<h2>Weight=<input type="text" id="wgt" onmouseout="bmi()"></h2>

<h2>BMI=<input type="text" id="student_bmi">
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function bmi(){
var sheight=parseFloat(document.getElementById('hgt').value);
var sweight=parseFloat(document.getElementById('wgt').value);
var bmi=sweight/Math.pow(sheight,2);
var student_bmi=document.getElementById('student_bmi').value;
student_bmi.textContent=bmi.toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

After insert value in the Height and Weight field, not display the calc in the BMI filed.

How to resolve this?

Comment: What's currently happening with your code? You should always post expected versus actual behavior, console errors, etc.

Comment: Also noticed your HTML is malformed; you didn't close the `type="text` attribute; is it just that typo? That would cause the `id="student_bmi"` attribute to be missed and cause the `document.getElementById('student_bmi')` call to not succeed.

Comment: Sorry, i have update the script. When i write the post not close the type

Comment: What's your expected behavior? The code is calculating BMI for the `onmouseout` event. Is that what you want, or do you want something different?

Comment: After insert of value in the Height filed, when mouse out, calc automatic bmi in the BMI filed

Comment: That sounds odd. Do you really want it to calculate when you move the mouse out of the field, or do you want it to calculate when you change what's in the input?

Comment: I want to calculate BMI when I change what's in the input Weight filed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onmouseout` event only fires when the mouse was inside of an element, then the mouse moves out of th element. This seems like an odd choice for when you calculate BMI, since the mouse probably doesn't move outside of the input during a typical user action.

A more straightforward approach would be to update the BMI whenever the content of either of the two inputs above change. You should consider also not using inline JavaScript event handlers in your HTML. Here's a different approach:

HTML:

```
<h2>Height=<input type="text" id="hgt"></h2>

<h2>Weight=<input type="text" id="wgt"></h2>

<h2>BMI=<input type="text" id="student_bmi"></h2>
```

JavaScript:

```
const heightInput = document.getElementById('hgt');
const weightInput = document.getElementById('wgt');
const bmiInput = document.getElementById('student_bmi');

heightInput.addEventListener('input', calculateBMI);
weightInput.addEventListener('input', calculateBMI);

function calculateBMI () {
  const height = parseFloat(heightInput.value);
  const weight = parseFloat(weightInput.value);
  const bmi = weight / Math.pow(height, 2);
  bmiInput.value = bmi.toFixed(2);
}
```

The `input` event, unlike the `mouseout` event, will fire for every keystroke, paste, or other input-altering events. You could also use the `change` event or `blur` depending on what you want the user experience to look like.